# multiple parameters for methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this method in application_helper

```
def is_controller?(*args)
 "active" if args.include?(params[:controller])
end
```

This works.

```
%= is_controller?("x") %>
```

This is not working.

```
%= is_controller?("x", "y", "z", "t") %>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: your code is valid. Why do you say it doesn't work?

Comment: please add the error message.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages, or is it just not working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the console it behaves as you expect

```
irb(main):020:0> def is_controller?(*args)
irb(main):021:1>    "active" if args.include?("x")
irb(main):022:1>   end
=> nil
irb(main):023:0> is_controller?("x")
=> "active"
irb(main):024:0> is_controller?("y")
=> nil
irb(main):025:0> is_controller?("x","y")
=> "active"
```

so the problem would seem to be that your params[:controller] value is not what you think it should be ...